# Can $\sum A_{i}X_{i}$ and $\sum B_{i}X_{i}$ be independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

Let $X_{i}$ bet i.i.d.
Also let $A_{i}$, $B_{i}$ be i.i.d. ($A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$ share same distribution) And $A_{i}, B_{i}, X_{i}$ are independent. (I mean, $A_{1}, \cdots , A_{n}, B_{1}, \cdots, B_{n}, X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ are independent) Also I have that $EA_{i} = EB_{i} = 0$

Then, my question is, can $\sum A_{i}X_{i}$ and $\sum B_{i}X_{i}$ be independent?
If not always, under what condition can we say that they are independent?

Or, is there any reasonable situation or intuition that we can consider these two terms are approximately independent? (Not rigorously independent, just approximately)

Comment: They aren’t independent. For example, take $A,B$ to be Rademacher random variables. And $X=0$ with probability $1/2$ and $X\neq 0$ with probability $1/2$. Then $P(AX = 0, BX \neq 0) = 0$ whereas $P(AX=0)P(BX\neq 0)>0$

Comment: @AndrewZhang But they can be: if $A_i,B_i,X_i$ are all Rademacher random variables (i.e. $\pm1$ with equal probabilities) then the sums will be independent.  Indeed if $X_i$ are Rademacher random variables and $A_i$ and $B_i$ have distributions symmetric about $0$ then the sums will be independent.